# Addresses of Computers Connected to an Unmanaged Switch

Tags: networking, switch

I've done a lot of googling, and I think I am using terrible terminology, because I haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm no networking professional, or even an amateur... Stack Overflow removed my question and punted me here to SuperUser, hopefully I'm in the right spot now!

Let's say I have a network that has a connection coming in from the router to an unmanaged switch. From this switch, there is a secondary layer of switches. (Say it was a 4-port switch. Each port (besides from the router) cascades out to another 4 port switch). I (a computer or microcontroller) am attached to one of these second-layer switches. See the diagram.

[Diagram of Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8XMX.png)

Is there any steps I can take to get the IP addresses of only the devices connected to the Layer 2 Switch to which I am connected (circled in red)?

Long story short, I am sketching out a project where I need a microcontroller(or a laptop for now) to be able to find devices at its local switch, and connect to local-network HTTP servers on each of only those particular devices it finds at its switch. And, the microcontroller or laptop should be able to differentiate those on its local switch from the wider network.

Answer (score 1):

No – there's no way for you, nor any software, to distinguish which devices are connected to which switch if they're all in the same subnet (except for physically unplugging things). Basically, *all* these switches in your diagram are parts of the same local network – it is **routers** that act as boundary between local and "the wider network".

In your case, either four separate VLANs going to the main router, or just four small "home wifi" routers replacing the four switches, would be the primary way to group devices. Another option would be to use port isolation on the main switch (sometimes called "private vlan") so that it wouldn't forward any packets between the smaller switches (while still allowing your "control" machines to talk to all of them).

**Other ideas:**

(If the switches were managed, they could be queried for their learned MAC→port mappings; by knowing that e.g. port 1 is the "uplink" port, you could use this to distinguish devices on same switch (MACs mapped to ports 2+) from those on a different switch (MACs mapped to port 1). Good managed switches can be queried in a standard way using SNMP, though of course this needs preparation, your devices would need to know the switches' SNMP credentials, and they *still* don't know which ports are considered "uplink" and which are not, so it can never be fully automated.)

However: *If* the switches were managed *and* had the LLDP discovery feature enabled in them (or the older Cisco CDP), then your devices could listen for LLDP packets and exchange the observed information with other devices, either as part of some custom discovery process or as part of the actual connection.

```
Switch->Port1: LLDP <This is ChassisID fc:e7:f5:51:28:0c, Port 1>
Switch->Port2: LLDP <This is ChassisID fc:e7:f5:51:28:0c, Port 2>
DevA->DevB: Hello <I'm DeviceA and I'm connected to ChassisID fc:e7:f5:51:28:0c>
DevB->DevA: Hello <I'm DeviceB and I'm connected to ChassisID fc:e7:f5:51:28:0c>
DevA->DevB: We're on the same switch! Let's talk
```

(LLDP discovery packets are unique in that switches are not supposed to forward them – at least managed switches do not; unmanaged ones still might! – so you'll see announcements only from the *nearest* switch that follows the rules.)

<sub>PCs can also speak LLDP; if you run Linux you have a choice between lldpd, ladvd, systemd-networkd.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Sounds like managed switches, consistently using port 1 as the "uplink" up the chain, would be exactly what I need to do. My scheme I have isn't married to unmanaged switches, so this is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend trying the LLDP approach first; many managed switches support LLDP nowadays, it requires much less configuration (practically zero) and is far more consistent from vendor to vendor. (Meanwhile, querying MAC tables via SNMP is a bit slower and – at least on the TP-Links that we have – sometimes fragile, not to mention SNMP itself is far from "simple.")

Comment: Awesome, will do!